# SQLite: How do I save the result of a query as a CSV file?

Tags: sqlite, csv

Is there a way I can export the results of a query into a CSV file?

Comment: Export from shell, one-liner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741408/911945

Answer (score 351, accepted):

From [here](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) and d5e5's comment:

You'll have to switch the output to csv-mode and switch to file output.

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output test.csv
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
sqlite> .output stdout
```

Comment: Use sqlite> .output C:/Users/jdoe/Documents/output.csv if you want to use a specific path.

Comment: Hi! I did this. Although my query worked perfectly, the file output is empty. Does someone knows why?

Comment: @ValeriaLobosOssandón this just happened to me, so i thought I'd respond. Either you don't have rights to edit the output file (unlikely), OR if you are viewing the CSVs in Excel, and have another Excel file open, even with your test.csv file closed, Excel will still lock it. In that case you would have to close all Excel windows first.

Comment: To get back to the default mode after `.mode csv` type `.mode list`  (or exit and restart)

Comment: how to achieve this with headers?

Answer (score 192):

To include column names to your csv file you can do the following:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output test.csv
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
sqlite> .output stdout
```

To verify the changes that you have made you can run this command:

```
sqlite> .show
```

Output:

```
echo: off   
explain: off   
headers: on   
mode: csv   
nullvalue: ""  
output: stdout  
separator: "|"   
stats: off   
width: 22 18
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to get the column names! This answer needs to be higher.

Comment: Note that  sqlite3 appends output to the end of the file without previous content erasing.

Comment: But each `.output filename.csv` execution creates or erases the file.

Answer (score 50):

In addition to the above answers you can also use `.once` in a similar way to `.output`. This outputs *only the next query* to the specified file, so that you don't have to follow with `.output stdout`.

So in the above example

```
.mode csv
.headers on
.once test.csv
select * from tbl1;
```

Answer (score 27):

Good answers from gdw2 and d5e5.  To make it a little simpler here are the recommendations pulled together in a single series of commands:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output test.csv
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
sqlite> .output stdout
```

Answer (score 22):

Alternatively you can do it in one line (tested in win10)

```
sqlite3 -help
sqlite3 -header -csv db.sqlite 'select * from tbl1;' > test.csv
```

Bonus: Using powershell with cmdlet and pipe (|).

```
get-content query.sql | sqlite3 -header -csv db.sqlite > test.csv
```

where query.sql is a file containing your SQL query

Answer (score 9):

All the existing answers only work from the sqlite command line, which isn't ideal if you'd like to build a reusable script.  Python makes it easy to build a script that can be executed programatically.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('your_cool_database.sqlite')

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * from orders', conn)
df.to_csv('orders.csv', index = False)
```

You can customize the query to only export part of the sqlite table to the CSV file.

You can also run a single command to export all sqlite tables to CSV files:

```py
for table in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';").fetchall():
    t = table[0]
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * from ' + t, conn)
    df.to_csv(t + '_one_command.csv', index = False)
```

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/sqlite/export-tables-queries-to-csv-parquet/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

While `.mode csv` and `.output` (or `.once`) commands are fine, they only work in SQLite command-line interface (aka `sqlite.exe` on Windows).

If you are not using the CLI, you can still write to an output file with the help of [sqlean-fileio](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/fileio.md) extension, using `fileio_append(path, string)` function.

For example:

```sql
create table people(id integer primary key, name text);

insert into people(id, name) values
(11, 'Alice'), (12, 'Bob'), (13, 'Cindy');

select sum(
    fileio_append('people.csv', format('%d,%s', id, name) || char('10'))
  )
from people;
```

After that, `people.csv` will have the following content:

```
11,Alice
12,Bob
13,Cindy
```