# Exporting data from Rails into XML and Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, xml, database

I use RubyOnRails and I want to get the data from within my database into an XML or Excel format.

How can I do it?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? SQLite? If so, you may find this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-to-export-the-results-of-my-query-to-csv-file-sqlite. Excel can easily handle CSV files.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice that you tagged the post with mysql. This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/356605/868691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting to XML is simple, you can call `to_xml` method on your items and render the result or use `render :xml`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

So for example, in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render xml: @items }
end
```

When it comes to Excel, there is a railscast on exporting to CSV (which can be easily imported to Excel) and XLS.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: Is there a way to get it to xml file in the rails c?

Comment: Sure, you can use the `to_xml` method on your collection and save the result into a file. For help with writing to files see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777802/how-to-write-to-file-in-ruby

Comment: after trying:

orders = Order.all_to_xml()

I got this error
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_xml' for #<Class:0x007f2d44f46988>

Comment: Try `orders = Order.all.to_xml`

Comment: do you know where the default location the xml file would be saved to?

Comment: You have to save the file yourself, such as `File.open('filename', 'w') { |f| f.write(Order.all.to_xml) }`; the file `filename` should be saved in the root folder of your app.

Comment: and after that I got a
63112976

returned in rails c, know what this means?

Comment: Looks like the number of characters written

Comment: awsome thanks, found the files in vim and now I just need to export them to excel and I'm done! I am so close thanks again for all your help Jacob

Comment: is there a way to save the to_xml file to desktop or any other directory on my computer? I am having a hard time getting those xml files out of vimT.T