# How do you extract all the tokens in a SQLite FTS table?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

For debugging purposes I want to see all the tokens that exist in a Full Text Search virtual table in SQLite.

When I look at the database structure for my FTS table (named `fts_table`) I see the following:

[image]

But browsing the data in these tables doesn't show the the list of tokens (not that I can find, anyway).

How do I extract a simple list of tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`ftx4aux`](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#fts4aux), which gives direct access to the full text index.

Use the following SQLite commands:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE search_terms USING fts4aux(fts_table);
SELECT term FROM search_terms WHERE col='*';
```

Read the documentation for a better understanding of how this works, but basically the `term` column stores the tokens and every instance of an asterisk (*) in the `col` column is a unique term.

If you need to export this to a text file, you can do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077039/3681880) from the command line:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output test.csv
sqlite> SELECT term FROM search_terms WHERE col='*';
sqlite> .output stdout
```

See also:

- [SQLite FTS3 and FTS4 Extensions](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)
- [The Spellfix1 Virtual Table](https://www.sqlite.org/spellfix1.html)
- [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html)

Comment: It's strange that when there is only one indexed column, the fts4aux table has every row duplicated: one with col='*', the other col='0'. Is it better to then do `WHERE col='*'` or `SELECT DISTINCT` (omitting the WHERE)?

Comment: @Mark, I haven't worked with fts tables for a while now so I can't answer your question at this time. If you continue playing around with this and answer your own question, please leave a comment or add a new answer.