# Sqlite3 fts5 search returns nothing if one of its phrases have a typo

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, full-text-search

It's **not** a duplicate question based on this:[Sqlite with real “Full Text Search” and spelling mistakes (FTS+spellfix together)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803014/sqlite-with-real-full-text-search-and-spelling-mistakes-ftsspellfix-together)

imagine a doc like:

```
'aaa bbb ccc ddd'
```

mysql query against it:

```
select * from table where match(doc) against('aaa bb ccc');
```

will load the data but sqlite3 fts5:

```
select * from table where  doc match 'aaa bb ccc';
```

will result nothing, is there any way for sqlite3 to ignore typographical errors like this when other phrases of query match?

(also I have tried '**OR**' operand in sqlite3 between each phrase but this will bring lots of irrelevant docs with only ONE match in query)

*reproducible example (on bash):*

```
$ sqlite3 testdb "create virtual table test using fts5(doc)";
$ sqlite3 testdb "insert into test values('aaa bbb ccc ddd');"
```

and simply get nothing:

```
 $ sqlite3 testdb "select * from test where doc match 'aaa bb ccc';"
```

while data has inserted correcly:

```
$ sqlite3 testdb "select * from test where doc match 'aaa bbb ccc';"
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

Comment: @Shawn for mysql yes, There's an implicit or between phrases but not sqlite.

Comment: Wait, yeah, it's an implicit and. I misread.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the % along with the query? I'm not sure of its usage with the match, though. For normal usage with LIKE, we use -> LIKE '%aaa bbb ccc%'.