# SQLite to CSV in Node

Tags: node.js, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

Is there a way, with SQLite3 for Node, to perform a query and either return it as a CSV file that I can then save locally, or have it save locally, automatically.

```
db.all("SELECT * FROM example WHERE foo = 'bar'", function (error, data) {
  // returns a JSON, I want a CSV file
});
```

Perhaps, something that can leverage or execute the commands presented in: [How do I save the result of a query as a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-do-i-save-the-result-of-a-query-as-a-csv-file)

Here's an example of what a solution might look like:

```
db.save("SELECT * FROM example WHERE foo = 'bar'", directory, filename, cb)
```

Comment: Surely you could simply convert the data object to a CSV-style string...

Comment: I could, except that the file I want to convert is ~1 GB. So I'd like to either stream the object in and convert it piecemeal, or I would like to have the operation performed as an export from SQL so I am no holding this massive JSON in memory.

Comment: Use the [`Statement#each`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) API.

Comment: I could use that, which lead me to a different problem, which I've brought up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702860/node-sqlites-db-each-using-large-amount-of-memory-for-broad-queries