# Node-SQLite's db.each using large amount of memory for broad queries

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I am attempting to run the below listed function in Node on a VM with 3.5GB of memory. The query I am running returns ~2.25 million rows. It fails due to what appears to be a memory leak - if someone has encountered this or has suggestions on how to handle the increasing memory problem on this call, I'd appreciate it.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

db.each(query, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Failed.');
    } else {
        console.log('Current perf: ', process.memoryUsage());
    }
    error = null; data = null;
}, function (error, responseLength) {
    console.log('done with all');
});
```

Each row looks like this:

```
2015-11-13T01:17:32Z|510|40.632087|-73.946855|315.47|2|20151112|9910715-SCPD5-SC_D5-Weekday-10-SDon|0|307840|73.51|5.53
```

The goal is to handle each row one at a time and write them to a CSV, line by line, via a stream. The thought was that, by doing this, I would avoid having to hold the entire query response in memory - but this goal seems to be thwarted given the current situation.

Comment: If you run the code I provided above, `console.log('Current perf: ', process.memoryUsage());` will show memory increases until process is killed. It never reached the callback function. I did not appreciate the down vote given other question is fundamentally different from this one.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that the memory continuously grows in your question then? And if that's happening, it's the SQLite binding's fault (I don't really consider node-sqlite3 to be a good binding, so I'm not surprised).

Comment: I've made that more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use a prepared statement and setImmediate(), like this:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var stmt = db.prepare(query);

doQuery();

function doQuery(){

    stmt.get(function(error, data){
        if(data){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                // do something with data here.
            }
            setImmediate(function(){
                doQuery();
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Explanation:

1) Prepared statements makes the client retrieve each row separately, rather than trying to grab all the results at once. The data param will be undefined when it hits the last row.

2) setImmediate() makes sure that the callback loop isn't called recursively, which could blow your call stack if the number of rows is too high.

Comment: After lokking for a while for this issue, you saved my life !