# Replicating Golang's synchronous WaitGroup in JavaScript (node.js) using the Atomics API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to replicate Golang's WaitGroup in JavaScript using the Atomics API.

The reason I need this is to add control in certain callback APIs that don't offer the ability to have async callbacks.

This is specifically for Node.js

A basic example:

```js
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3'

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./data.db')
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

db.each('SELECT * from my_table', async (err, row) => {
  console.log('start', row)
  await sleep(2000)
  console.log('done', row)
});
```

Each iteration will not care for the Promise returned by the callback and will instead flip through all of the rows immediately. This API does not offer me the ability to go row by row to minimize CPU overhead.

While this is one example and perhaps the answer is to open a PR to the library, there are many similar examples and it's more practical to have a solution I can implement on my end to address this while raising an issue with the maintainers.

I have since discovered the [new Atomics API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics) which offers the ability to sleep threads.

As an example here is a thread blocking sleep for 500ms.

```js
const sleep = milliseconds => Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, milliseconds)

sleep(500)
```

Obviously it's not ideal to use thread blocking techniques but in this case I believe it's appropriate.

I would like to produce a wrapper around Atomics that allows for the same control flow management as Golang's [sync.WaitGoup](https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups)

Assuming the following interface, producing a wrapper is challenging.

```js
interface SyncWaitGroup {
   new (ticks: number): SyncWaitGroup
   done(): void
   wait(): void
}
```

Where its usage would be

```js
db.each('SELECT * from my_table', (err, row) => {
  console.log('start', row)
  const wg = new SyncWaitGroup(1) // WaitGroup wants 1 call to done() 

  setTimeout(() => {
    wg.done() // This call will satisfy the required number of done() calls
  }, 2000)

  wg.wait() // synchronously wait for all the done() calls
  console.log('done', row)
});
```

Using this strategy to force the callback to be executed synchronously allows me to write a wrapper that converts `db.each` into an `AsyncIterable` where I could use it idiomatically from there.

The issue I am having is understanding the Atomics API. Attempting something like this fails as the thread (including the event loop) is sleeping and mutations to the input array are not tracked.

```js
const int32 = new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4))

setTimeout(() => { 
  // Lives on the same thread so it's blocked
  Atomics.store(int32, 0, 1)
  Atomics.notify(int32, 0);
  console.log('fired') // Does not run
}, 2000)

Atomics.wait(int32, 0, 0)
```

Comment: If `wg.wait()` blocks, it also blocks the `setTimeout` callback from occurring. You really need to wait for the shared buffer being modified by a *different thread*, that is, a worker.

Comment: You can try bottleneck or p-limit to limit the number of concurrent calls. However, I think the correct answer is in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702860/node-sqlites-db-each-using-large-amount-of-memory-for-broad-queries).

Comment: @Bergi, yeah - unlike Go, `setTimeout` doesn't spawn a new thread so `Atomics.wait` would block all further execution. I was hopeful there would be another solution. I could perhaps write a utility in C++, offering Node bindings to create `SyncWaitGroup`