# specify the path in .output

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to save the result of my query into a .csv file. this is how I am doing it.

```
.output train1.csv
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

The problem is that when I specify a path in .output, the output get displayed on screen as oppose saved in the specified .csv file.

```
 .output ~/PycharmProjects/ROSSMANN/input/crossval/train1.csv
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-do-i-save-the-result-of-a-query-as-a-csv-file

Comment: I know how to save to a cvs file. but I want to specify the path to that file.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is not a valid directoy name. The shell will replace it with the home directory, but most other programs don't know about it.

Use the actual directory name:

```
.output /home/MAS/PycharmProjects/ROSSMANN/input/crossval/train1.csv
```

Comment: Changing it didn't fix my problem. /Users/mas/PycharmProjects/ROSSMANN/input/crossval/train1.csv