# Insert SQL data to txt file

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database named = many_cars with the table "cars" and im trying to copy all the cars with the color = silver and make = ford and ORDER BY LicenseNumber to my txt file called silver-ford.txt. What i have tried is to first

This should be done in bash and with SQLITE3

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE Color='Silver' AND Make='Ford'
ORDER BY LicenseNumber
INSERT INTO silver-fords.txt
```

Comment: You need to write some kind of a script. e.g write a python script that runs that query and writes the output to a txt file

Comment: @JonEkiz im pretty sure thats not needed.. there must be something im missing or not thinking about.

Comment: maybe this helps ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-do-i-save-the-result-of-a-query-as-a-csv-file

Comment: You can do that using cmd

Comment: What OS are you runing? Do you have SQLITE3 client installed?

Comment: Running osx, sorry for not saying that this should be done in bash and yes with SQLITE3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very nice [tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-export-csv/). CSV is the same as TXT - simply flat file, you can change extention after exprot, if you like.

Choose a mode, set header option and set destination. Than run your select

```
.headers on
.mode csv
.output data.csv
SELECT...
```