# export DB in CSV format android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have searched many places including this resource to find any examples of how to export my DB table in a CSV format. Any ideas or suggestions please. I want to do this by code , not with a shell script. I already have code that exports the DB as a backup, now I want to export the table contents so they can be viewed in a spreadsheet application.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been answered here: [Export from sqlite to csv using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776660/export-from-sqlite-to-csv-using-shell-script)

If that doesn't work try editing the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way of doing this.

You'll need to query the table (example, "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE") then use the `getColumnNames()` method of the `Cursor` to get a `String[]` of the column names which you can then use with a `StringBuilder` to create the first line of the csv file, example...

`column1,column2,column3`

You then move through the `Cursor` and cycle through the column names array and get the value for each column...

`getString(getColumnIndex(columnNames[x]));`

...and pass the string returned to a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the values to write to the file...

`value1,value2,value3`