# How to convert an sqlite database to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sqlite

How do you convert an sqlite database (generated by Rails) to a collection of JSON objects? Is there a set of scripts/ a ruby gem that does that, or is it necessary to code something from scratch?

Comment: If you had a csv -> json, then you could hack it together with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776660/export-from-sqlite-to-csv-using-shell-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand the question, but here's a stab.

If you have a collection called Widgets, you can call `Widgets.all.to_json` This is trivial to do in a Rails Console session.

You can then simply output that to where every you like, such as a text file.

Other ways would be to use a db dump task via rake `rake -T` will show you the available commands.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I also extended the String class to easily save to file, like this: http://pleaselistencarefully.com/String-to_file-the-easiest-way-to-write-a-string-to-a-file-in-ruby