# Most efficient way to output a large table to multiple csv file based on column value

Tags: sqlite

I have a 1 GB table, I need to output the db to multiple csv files based on column value. For instance:

```
c1              |   c2                  |   c3

1               |   a                   |   100    
2               |   b                   |   102    
3               |   a                   |   103    
4               |   b                   |   104
```

to be:

a.csv

```
1               |   a                   |   100    
3               |   a                   |   103
```

b.csv

```
2               |   b                   |   102
4               |   b                   |   104
```

considering the size of table, what's the most efficient way to do this?

Update: 
so far I have been able to do `select * from table_name order by c2;` and `.mode csv .out a.csv select * from table_name;` on a smaller sample of the dataset. I was wondering what are alternative except looping through all item manually.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: First get it [working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776660/export-from-sqlite-to-csv-using-shell-script), then run it through [explain query plan](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html), have a guess as to what you want, post it here, and people will be more willing to help you