# python application that queries a database

Tags: python, database, user-interface

I need to develop a GUI desktop application that takes input from the user, does some calculations, and then runs a bunch of queries which should be exported into a csv, xls or txt file. I want to create an installation package which the user can install without installing any other applications (used for front end) and other database (other than MS Access). My questions are

1. If I use python for my front-end/GUI, can I create an installation package? I understand that we can create and .exe file from the .py file. I want the dB to be get copied in the right folder (path referenced in my program) on the end-user's computer when the user installs the package.
2. MS Access (2010) on my computer (Windos 7 OS) is 32-bit and I'm having trouble using it with 64-bit python (version 3.5.1) and pyodbc(version 3.0.10). Can I use any alternate dB (sqlite?) that the user doesn't have to install to run the application and I don't have to worry about getting the dB in the right folder on the end-users computer. My dB is very small (few tables with about 1000 rows each).

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can do both - pyinstaller seems to support sqlite3, the python library for working with sqlite which seems like a great fit for your use case:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/3.0

About exporting - you can write code for that using python, depends on the  exact output you are looking for.

Here's an example of using sqlite tools for basic export:
[Export from sqlite to csv using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776660/export-from-sqlite-to-csv-using-shell-script)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Your response was very helpful.

Comment: great, glad to hear! please mark my answer as the answer if that solves it, tnx