# Reading from CSV, updating a value and then re-writing

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to read from a csv file and then update a field based on a users selection and write the contents (including the amendment) to a new csv file. I have managed everything but my solution only writes the amended line and not the rest of the files contents.

The csv file looks like:

```
1001, item1, 0.5, 10
1002, item2, 1.5, 20
```

Here is an example of my attempt:

```
run="yes"
while run=="yes":
    id=input("Enter the id of the product you want to order: ")
    amount=input("Enter the quantity: ")

    reader = csv.reader(open('items.csv', 'r'))
    writer = csv.writer(open('updatedstock.csv','w'))

    for row in reader:
        if id==row[0]:
            name=row[1]
            price=row[2]
            stock=row[3]
            newstock=int(stock)-int(amount)
            writer.writerow([id, name, price, newstock])

    run=input("Do you want to order another item? yes/no ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently only writing to the new file if you match the id based on the condition:

```
if id==row[0]:
```

Change it to always write the row:

```
run="yes"

while run=="yes":
    id=input("Enter the id of the product you want to order: ")
    amount=input("Enter the quantity: ")

    reader = csv.reader(open('items.csv', 'r'))
    writer = csv.writer(open('updatedstock.csv','w'))

    for row in reader:
        if id==row[0]:
            name=row[1]
            price=row[2]
            stock=row[3]
            newstock=int(stock)-int(amount)
            writer.writerow([id, name, price, newstock])
        else:
            writer.writerow(row)

    run=input("Do you want to order another item? yes/no ")
```

If you plan to replace many values, however, this can be very inefficient as the csv will be read in for each change. It would be better to read in all values that you want to change and then go through the csv, modifying the entries desired.

Even better would be to use some other data structure like SQLite that performs better with finds and writes. Of course, this would not be as easily human-readable format as it sits in the filesystem. You can easily output the sqlite database to a .csv if needed: [Export from sqlite to csv using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776660/export-from-sqlite-to-csv-using-shell-script).

Comment: Also, **seriously(!)** consider using SQLite!  *As long as you use transactions(!),* this is an excellent and high-performance way to "manage a data-file."  An SQLite database *is* "a single file."  No external server is required.  And, the SQLite team has done an excellent job of making it deliver consistently excellent performance.

Comment: The only caveat ... and it is a very important one ... is that you *must* use transactions in order to achieve "lazy writes."  Otherwise, SQLite will physically verify every read and write, causing it to be unexpectedly (very) slow.  When transactions are used for reads *and* writes, it performs like a winged mammal from a hot place.  **:-D**