# Save RSQLite Query Results to csv Without Reading them into R

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I am working with a large SQLite database, and I am using RSQLite and Rstudio to run many different queries at the same time. Many times the results of the queries are quite large, and I don't want to waste resources by reading them into R and then saving them to CSV. I would prefer to have the database itself manage this. However, this does not work and I'm not sure what else to try.

```
library(RSQLite)
db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "test.sqlite")

dbWriteTable(db, "iris", iris)

dbListTables(db)


sql <- ".headers on
.mode csv
.output C:/Users/jmc6538/Documents/testing/setosa.csv
SELECT * FROM iris WHERE Species = 'setosa';"

result <- dbSendQuery(db, sql)
```

Which produces this error

```
> result <- dbSendQuery(db, sql)
Error: near ".": syntax error
```

I've tried putting in various combinations of escape characters and that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `dbExecute` instead of `dbSendQuery`?  Also, you could remove the `result <-` and just have `dbExecute(db, sql)`

Comment: using `dbExecute` didn't work either. Got the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax here is not accepted because these instructions are based on the SQLite tool.
These are not simple sql statements but rather command lines to this tool:

1. Install the sqlite command line utility from [here](https://sqlite.org/cli.html)
2. Follow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741408/5224236) instructions, perhaps modifying for use in R, such as

   `shell('sqlite3 -header -csv c:/sqlite/chinook.db "select * from tracks;" > tracks.csv')`

Make sure that `SQLite3` is in your path, by opening a cmd and typing `sqlite3`. If you have the error `sqlite is not recognized`, then you'd need to add the installation folder containing `sqlite3.exe` or similar to the path. Or you could set the working directory in R to

```
setwd("C:/[installation folder containing sqlite3.exe]")
shell('sqlite3 -header -csv c:/sqlite/chinook.db "select * from tracks;" > tracks.csv')
```

Comment: Oooh, This is a good suggestion, I didn't think about just sending the query through the command line. I already had the command line utility, and it almost works. The redirect command isn't working. This is what I have, `system('sqlite3 -header -csv C:/Users/jmc6538/Documents/testing/test.sqlite "select * from iris where Species = \'setosa\';" > test.csv')` and the output in R prints the data and says `Error: near ">": syntax error` Any suggestions. Tried specifying the full path and that didn't do anything.

Comment: It is because I am on Windows...of course. According to `system()` docs, `This means that it cannot be assumed that redirection or piping will work in system (redirection sometimes does, but we have seen cases where it stopped working after a Windows security patch), and system2 (or shell) must be used on Windows.` `system2()` didn't work for me, but `shell()` did.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing some bench marking for this comparing the accepted answer with reading the table into R and then saving to csv since my goal was to cut down on compute time. Thought others might find this helpful and the results are fairly interesting. I tested it on my windows laptop as well as a super computer that I have access to. I did three different size tables for each environment.

For my laptop this was the commands.

```
microbenchmark(
  sys = {shell('sqlite3 -header -csv C:/Users/jmc6538/Documents/testing/test.sqlite "select * from iris;" > C:/Users/jmc6538/Documents/testing/test.csv')},
  RSQLite = {
    db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "test.sqlite")
    result <- dbSendQuery(db, sql)
    write.csv(dbFetch(result), "./test2.csv")
    dbClearResult(result)
    dbDisconnect(db)
  })
```

The different sized tables were a single copy of the `iris` data (150 rows), the `iris` data set 4,502 times (675,300 rows), and the `iris` data set 450,200 times (6,753,000 rows). Here are the results in the same order.

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval cld
     sys 213.758862 216.612667 223.37484 217.858642 218.88561 342.42205   100   b
 RSQLite   6.981669   7.663255  10.08729   9.377483  10.90106  25.52816   100  a 

Unit: seconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
     sys 10.633965 11.788077 12.844148 12.967207 13.757598 16.142357   100   b
 RSQLite  5.164632  6.791199  7.172043  7.351825  7.728878  8.486433   100  a 

Unit: seconds
    expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
     sys 94.38379 101.36282 103.49785 102.98158 104.52018 114.95047   100   b
 RSQLite 48.48948  50.28782  53.18634  53.64562  55.80938  63.87987   100  a
```

So on my laptop, using `RSQLite` and `write.csv` was always faster by a significant amount.

On the super computer the number of rows were 150, 900,000, and 9,000,000, and the commands were

```
microbenchmark(
  sys = {system('sqlite3 -header -csv C:/Users/jmc6538/Documents/testing/test.sqlite "select * from iris;" > C:/Users/jmc6538/Documents/testing/test.csv')},
  RSQLite = {
    db <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "test.sqlite")
    result <- dbSendQuery(db, sql)
    write.csv(dbFetch(result), "./test2.csv")
    dbClearResult(result)
    dbDisconnect(db)
  })
```

And the results.

[image: Super Computer Benchmark Results]

On the super computer using the `system` call was faster for the larger tables, but not for the small table.

Edit:
Using `data.table`'s `fwrite` to write the CSVs sped up the RSQLite method over the shell method on the super computer. I only did 10 repeats here for the 900,000 and 9,000,000 table because I didn't want to wait for 100. I think this is the better method if people are looking for speed.

[image]